# Shortcodes function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Here the problem:

I have two div #post-playlist-list and post-playlist-description

I want to use two shortcodes [texte-article] and [playlist-article]

I need a function which get all the content between[texte-article][/texte-article] to put in #post-playlist-list

and another function which get the [playlist-article][/playlist-article] content into #post-playlist-description

I began to learn at preg_replace but the syntax is not that easy to learn.

I you can help me on this, it would be great.

Ok i tried the function i don't have error but it doesn't seems to return anything
Don't i need to escape the second ] ion the Regexp? like "/[texte-article](.*)[/texte-article]/"

Here's the code in my single.php :

```
        <div id="post-playlist-list" class="box">
        <?php 
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $post = get_post($id);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
        $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
        echo $content;
        ?>
        </div>
        <div id="post-playlist-description" >
        <?php
        echo $content;
        ?>
        </div>
```

Here's the code in my single.php:

```
    function texte_article_function() {

    preg_replace_callback("/\[texte-article\](.*)\[\/texte-article\]/", function($matches) {
      //$matches contains an array of all matches
      //$matches[0] stores the full pattern match: \[texte-article](.*)\[\/texte-article]
      //$matches[1] stores the first subpattern match: (.*)
      //Do whatever text parsing you need to do here and return the result.
    $content = $matches[0];
      return $content;
 }, $postdata);

}

function playlist_article_function() {

    preg_replace_callback("/\[playlist-article\](.*)\[\/playlist-article\]/", function($matches) {
      //$matches contains an array of all matches
      //$matches[0] stores the full pattern match: \[texte-article](.*)\[\/texte-article]
      //$matches[1] stores the first subpattern match: (.*)
      //Do whatever text parsing you need to do here and return the result.
    $content = $matches[0];
      return $content;
 }, $postdata);

}


function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('texte-article', 'texte_article_function');
    add_shortcode('playlist-article', 'playlist_article_function');
}
    add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Comment: You should not need preg_replace for this. Are you trying to insert text in a template? if so, why not insert the text directly instead of surrounding it with a shortcode? If you are not trying to insert in a template, where are these two divs?

Comment: Yep, i thought about that then. Easier to implement but i wanted to use regular expression and shortcode to avoid users to have to put code. And with shortcodes i can then use tinymce to create a shortcode button. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers :) here's the solution, using regex:

**functions.php**

```
  function texte_article_function($content_texte_article) {
        //Get [texte-article] content
        $content_texte_article = preg_replace('#.*\[texte-article\](.*)\[\/texte-article\].*#s', '$1', $content_texte_article);
        return $content_texte_article;
    }

function playlist_article_function($content_playlist_article) {
    //get [fap_playlist] content
    $content_playlist_article = preg_replace('#.*\[playlist-article\](.*)\[\/playlist-article\].*#s', '$1', $content_playlist_article);
    return $content_playlist_article;
}
```

**Callback functions:**

```
<?php 
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $post = get_post($id);
            $content_playlist_article = $content;
            $btn_play_index_id = $content;
            echo playlist_article_function($content_playlist_article);
            // echo $content;
            ?>
            <?php
            $content_texte_article = $content;
            echo texte_article_function($content_texte_article);                
    ?>
```

If it can help someone.